# DataMapper Adapter for MS SqlServer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, orm, datamapper

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am planning to use SQLServer as the database for my application. For ORM, i did some searching and it is recommended to use DataMapper over ActiveRecords. But i cannot find any adapter from DataMapper to use with SqlServer. Are there any adapters available? I was able to find one but that will work only with JRuby and JDBC drivers which is not my dev environment. If there isn't one can you recommend the best available ORM for SQLServer?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-sqlserver-adapter)?

Comment: I tried using that. It required do_sqlserver. When i tried installing do_sqlserver it requires JRuby as you can see in the requirments in the link below: https://github.com/datamapper/do/tree/master/do_sqlserver